# url matching /app, /app/.* but not /app-foo

Tags: regex

Trying to use [Java's regexp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

I want to match /app, /app/.* , but not /app-foo  .. any hints ?

The  '/app/?.*'  doesn't work    and '/app\b/?.*' matches /app-foo

any quick soln ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/app(?:/.*)?
```

Explanation:

- `/app` match the "/app" string
- `(?:` start of a optional group (non capturing)

  - `/.*` match any string starting with `/`
- `)?` end the optional group

Comment: yeah that should work ... the only thing is (? is start of non capturing group .. which is what i needed .. Thx